# image sharelatex in another place of code

Tags: image, latex, height, sharelatex

chapitre1.tex, line 32
Package keyval Error: heigth undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...

l.32 ...[heigth=6cm,width=5cm]{img/e-commerce.png}

Try typing    to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X   to quit.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The key defined by [`graphicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) for specifying the height of including graphics is `height`, not `heigth`:

```
\includegraphics[height = 6cm, width = 5cm]{img/e-commerce.png}
```